# liac-arff to read arff file TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, arff

i want to read arff file but i am getting this error. Could any one help me with this

```
import arff, numpy as np
dataset = arff.load(open('ckdfull.arff', 'rb'))
data = np.array(dataset['data'])


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ckd/ckd.py", line 2, in <module>
        dataset = arff.load(open('ckdfull.arff', 'rb'))

      File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\ckd\venv\lib\site-packages\arff.py", line 896, in load
        return_type=return_type)

      File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\ckd\venv\lib\site-packages\arff.py", line 739, in decode
        matrix_type=return_type)

      File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\ckd\venv\lib\site-packages\arff.py", line 651, in _decode
        row = row.strip(' \r\n')

    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Thank You

Comment: change 'rb'(read binary) to 'r' (read) and try..

Comment: i tried in read mode ..but again i am getting error 

arff.BadNominalValue: Data value not found in nominal declaration, at line 67.

Comment: I think [this link](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff/blob/master/arff.py#L226) will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank You for your response :) ..actually there were extra commas and tab space in arff file...i formatted data properly with notepad

Now its working fine.